# security-role-assignment, migrating from weblogic to jboss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a weblogic-application.xml file as follows:

```
<weblogic-application ...>
  <security>
    <security-role-assignment>
      <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
      <principal-name>AdministratorsType1</principal-name>
      <principal-name>AdministratorsType2</principal-name>
    </security-role-assignment>
    ...
  </security>
</weblogic-application>
```

and a web.xml as follows:

```
<web-app ...>
  ...
  <security-role>
    <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
  </security-role>
  ...
</web-app>
```

---

now, the way of mapping roles names at security-role-assignment is weblogic-specific,
and i have to migrate to boss.
how do I rewrite this security-role-assignment in jboss?=

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MappingRolesInJBossApplicationServerV5x